# How do I create a static "header" in the Console C#?

Tags: c#, user-interface

Okay, normally I would paste code that I have been working on, but I literally have no clue where to start. If someone could give me a reference or some general idea of how to construct this, I would be very grateful.

So what I'm doing is creating a 'hangman' game. What I would like is a static (unmoving)header at the top of the console that will always display every letter of the alphabet (and strikethrough any letters already guessed) as well as the _ _ _ for the missing letters.

I'm also wanting to be able to draw (ASCII I assume) a gallow that is unmoving on the right side of the console. Essentially, it will look like a MUD with the 'userinput' within the main part, but with static header and sidebar.

I do not want anyone to write this for me, not at all. I just want to be pointed in the right direction and given a general idea of how something like that would be created and how it would function within the console (or a reference to documentation that would explain all of that). I looked, but I can't find anything. :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Console.SetCursorPosition`

Comment: Check out [curses-sharp](http://curses-sharp.sourceforge.net/) (when sourceforge comes back online)

Comment: I would have a static class that has different states (output). So based on the number of incorrect guesses, the state changes and you reprint the header with, let's say, an `O` as the head, as well as reprinting anything else with their states.

Comment: @AndrewGrinder yes, I did that (I think? - I edited my question since I figured out how to get it to work). So using the console, I won't be able to get around it fully reprinting when a state changes?

Comment: @Newbie One question at a time please. You extend your question with every feedback, invalidating already posted answers....

Comment: @EZI Heck, I was afrait to re-post the question. lol. I thought I'd be told "you should've appended this question to your last question."

Most forums make you do that (non-programming forums). My bad. I'll re-post and re-edit.

Comment: @EZI And thank you for your clear, concise response. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `Console.SetCursorPosition` to control where output is being written.

Here's [MSDN's article on Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Console_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).